# How to make gridPanel's Horizontal scroll RIGHT to LEFT in extjs3.4?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

> I want my grid panel's horizontal scroll works from right to left to support RTL in extj3.4. I have overridden css. Everything is working fine but horizontal scroll works from left to right instead right to left. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                title:gridtitle,
                border: false,
                height: getGridHeight(),
                autoScroll:true,
                store: store,
                id:'grid',
                colModel: cm,
                selModel: selmodel,
                loadMask: true,
                plugins: [filters],        
                bbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
                })
            });
```